# Reactjs react-bootstrap js error

Tags: reactjs, sails.js, react-bootstrap

I built react app based on this repo:

```
    https://github.com/wi2/isomorphic-sails-react-example
```

now i'm implementing react-bootstrap following their getting started instruction. I tried navigation bar demo but got broken display and javascript error when i tried to do simple behaviour like collapse/uncollapse dropdown menu.

navigation.js

```
"use strict";

import React from 'react'
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap'

export class Navigation {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar inverse>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Nav>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
            <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem divider />
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
          <Nav pullRight>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link Right</NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link Right</NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    )
  }
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuU0U.png)

Did i miss something like i have to include some js libraries?

Comment: What version of React-bootstrap are you using? Latest version needs an updated React (isomorphic-sails-react-example is using 0.13.3)

Answer (score 0):

Try extending React Component with your Navigation class

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap'

export class Navigation extends Component {
...
```